# Should I rename too localized question title?

Tags: discussion, questions

Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673341/why-my-regex-let-me-write-comma).

The OP choosed the title **Why my Regex let me write “,” (Comma)?** in belief that there is some exception for comma in his Regex, but the real problem was different. Should I rename it to something like **Regex character set syntax** to make it clear for others, or should I leave it as is, not to confuse the OP?

Comment: Meh, I'd probably leave it.  It's a part of the category of changes in which you're editing the question as a result of finding the answer.  While you sometimes can, it makes a lot of people wary.  Searching for dups now.

Comment: The title is correct: The OP is wondering why the regular expression he used allows the comma as input. The title you suggest is a rather generic title that could be used for many questions about regular expressions.